# Azure WebJobs Scheduler

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler

Can we have multiple Schedules in a Single web Job of Microsoft Azure.
We have certain functionalities  to happen in a single job within particular time 
i.e multiple schedules so we have tried through the timer but i need to know is there any other option.Thank you

Comment: My concern is can we have multiple schedules for a single web job sir.The above suggestion is helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TimerTriggerAttribute: Please refer https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger

```
// Triggered every hours
public static void HourlyTimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:01:00")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine("Your first scheduled job!");
}


// Triggered every 15 minutes
public static void MinutelyTimerJob([TimerTrigger("00:00:15")] TimerInfo timerInfo, TextWriter log)
{
    log.WriteLine("Your second scheduled job!");
}
```

Comment: Yes i have already used the timer trigger attribute and its working Thank you for the suggestion.But any information on Multiple schedule on single webjob or other options if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use CRON expression for web jobs to e.g., let it run at particular times. You can refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatescheduledcronacreate-a-scheduled-webjob-using-a-cron-expression).